# parse-Server cloudCode with nodejs

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, webhooks, parse-server

I am using parse-server and I want to use nodejs with cloudCode as in the example below.

This is the example:
[Adding nodejs to Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/)

here is the example code from the link

```
    var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ParseCloud = require('parse-cloud-express');
var Parse = ParseCloud.Parse;
var app = express();
// Host static files from public/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// Define a Cloud Code function:
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success('Hello from Cloud Code on Node.');
});
// Mount the Cloud Code routes on the main Express app at /webhooks/
// The cloud function above will be available at /webhooks/function_hello
app.use('/webhooks', ParseCloud.app);
// Launch the HTTP server
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Cloud Code on Node running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

console.log(process.env.PORT);

I have imported all the required modules, but still, when I run the server and try to go to the link "127.0.0.1/webhooks/function_hello" I get back `Cannot GET /webhooks/function_hello`

Any advise?

*OUTPUT when i run the script *

```
    undefined
Cloud Code on Node running on port 80.
```

**UPDATE** it seems that with parse's shutdown that they have changed support status for cloudcode which affects integrating it with NodeJs

Comment: Can you please add the output from the console when you execute the server?

Comment: Try Post 127.0.0.1:80/webhooks/functions/hello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. GET doesn't work here. You need to make a **POST** request, and then you'll get `{"success":"Hello from Cloud Code on Node."}`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are running the right script with `node SCRIPT_NAME`

It appears your express server is set to port 5000.

See: `var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

Change your URL to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/webhooks/function_hello` or `localhost:5000/webhooks/function_hello` and it should appear

If you want to run on the default port (80) you will need to run with `sudo` for your script and make the following change to the code.

`var port = process.env.PORT || 80;`

Add a folder to your directory named `public`.  Inside that folder place a file named `index.html`.  Type `Hello World` in that file, save it.  Restart your server.  See if you can open http://127.0.0.1/.

Comment: I have ensured that i am running the right script and i tried port 80 as you have suggested. however  neither http://127... nor localhost:80..etc are returning a result other than "Cannot GET /webhooks/function_hello"

Comment: @user3676224, I have updated the instructions to include the port change.  If that does not work, please tell me the output of console.log(process.env.PORT).

Comment: it has resulted in "undefined", the output is "undefined
Cloud Code on Node running on port 80." **UPDATE** i just want to show you how i placed it " var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Cloud Code on Node running on port ' + port + '.');
});

console.log(process.env.PORT);"

Comment: Added additional test instructions to answer

Comment: Thank you for your help Duane, but it seems parse have changed support status for cloudcode which affects integrating it with NodeJs